# apt-get on Mac OS X?

Tags: macos, aptitude

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Apple / Mac OS X - Is there a Package Manager like Linux](https://superuser.com/questions/92872/apple-mac-os-x-is-there-a-package-manager-like-linux)

Is there a version of apt-get on Mac OS X?  If not, or it is not recommended, what similar installers are there?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have [homebrew](https://brew.sh/), [mac ports](https://www.macports.org/) and [Fink](https://www.finkproject.org/) otherwise there is no default thing like Advanced Packaging Tool (apt) :(  It is completely up to you it is easier to install programs and things via APT. I don't i just usually build from source.
Dean